How to remove duplicate key from a Json object with DataWeave?
I need to merge two arrays of objects based on a common field, keeping the objects that are present in both arrays and combining their fields.
I am getting duplicate keys after merging two arrays. How to remove duplicate keys in JSON?
DW Script
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Arrays

output application/json
var array1 = [
  { "id": 1, "name": "John" },
  { "id": 2, "name": "Jane" }
]

var array2 = [
  { "id": 1, "age": 30 },
  { "id": 3, "age": 25 },
  { "id": 2, "age": 25 }
]

var mergeArray = array1 map((item) ->
    array2 filter((item2, index) -> (item2.id == item.id)) map (item2) -> 
        (item2 ++ item)
)
---
flatten(mergeArray)

Output - Getting duplicate id
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "age": 30,
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "age": 25,
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Jane"
  }
]


Instead of trying to filter duplicated keys with your approach I recommend to use the join() function from the Arrays module. It is simpler and you only need to map the results from each side into a single object. You can map each key that you want in the output explicitly or you can add of them and remove the duplicate key from one. Examples for both methods are below.
Mapping each key explicitly
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Arrays

output application/json
var array1 = [
  { "id": 1, "name": "John" },
  { "id": 2, "name": "Jane" }
]

var array2 = [
  { "id": 1, "age": 30 },
  { "id": 3, "age": 25 },
  { "id": 2, "age": 25 }
]
---
join(array1, array2, (item) -> item.id, (item) -> item.id)
   map { id: $.l.id, age: $.r.age, name: $.l.name}

Output:
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "age": 30,
    "name": "John"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "age": 25,
    "name": "Jane"
  }
]

Removing a key from one side
If you don't want to explicitly map every field you can just add all the key-pairs from both sides and remove the id key from one of them:
join(array1, array2, (item) -> item.id, (item) -> item.id)
   map ($.l ++ ($.r -"id"))


We can achieve this with filter() and flatten()
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var array1 = [
  { "id": 1, "name": "John" },
  { "id": 2, "name": "Jane" }
]

var array2 = [
  { "id": 1, "age": 30 },
  { "id": 3, "age": 25 },
  { "id": 2, "age": 25 }
]

var mergeArray = array1 map((item) ->
    array2 filter((item2, index) -> (item2.id == item.id)) 
    map ($ ++ ($ - 'id'))       
)
---
flatten(mergeArray)


%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Arrays 
output application/json skipNullOn = "everywhere"
var array1 = [
  { "id": 1, "name": "John" },
  { "id": 2, "name": "Jane" }
]

var array2 = [
  { "id": 1, "age": 30 },
  { "id": 3, "age": 25 },
  { "id": 2, "age": 25 }
]

---
 flatten((array2 map ((item, index) -> array1 map ((item1, index1) -> 
 if(item.id == item1.id)
 {
     "id" : item1.id,
     "age" : item.age,
     "id" : item.id,
     "name" : item1.name,
     
 }
 else
  null 

 ))) filter ((item, index) -> item != ""))


While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
